# How to make youtube video exit fullscreen when the video is done

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube iOS API helper in order to show videos. Most users will want to view the videos in fullscreen, but after watching the video, the app needs to exit the fullscreen video so that users can complete related tasks. Is there a way to exit the video on videoEnded.

Comment: Can you not just call - (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state {} and check when the player has stopped and then exit your player?

Comment: I don't see a way of exiting the player. I know I can track the state in that way, but then I'm stuck in fullscreen until the user hits Done

Comment: Can you not programmatically click the done button when finshed playing?

Comment: Do you have an action that is called when the button is pressed?

Comment: No. All of that is handled by the iframe created by youtube (I think).

Answer (score 0):

In the *playerVars* dictionary you should set a property `@"autohide" : @1`
That Will make the video exit full screen after the video is done.
It will look something like this:

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{@"autohide" : @1};
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.videoID playerVars:playerVars];
```

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me,
source https://gist.github.com/akisute/a46c5ec54d27f73b62da

```
- (void)exitFullScreenVideo:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(void))completion
    {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 8.0) {
            BOOL isFullScreenVideoContent = NO;
            for (UIWindow *window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
                if ([window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"AVFullScreenViewController")]) {
                    [window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^{
                        window.rootViewController = nil;
                        window.hidden = YES;
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
                        [window performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"release")];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                        completion();
                    }];
                    isFullScreenVideoContent = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isFullScreenVideoContent) {
                completion();
            }
        } else {
            completion();
        }
    }
```